# Почему num undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function getNum() {
  var content = prompt('Enter number:');
  var result = cnvertNum(content);
  console.log(result);
  if (result == true) {
    return content;
  } else {
    getNum();
  }
}

function cnvertNum(content) {
  var int = parseInt(content);
  if (!isNaN(int)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

var num = getNum();
console.log(num);
```

Comment: перезапустите, все работает - https://jsbin.com/poqafem/edit?html,js,output

Comment: если раз ввести неправильно то следующие попытки дадут undefined

Comment: Результат getNum вернет, если `if (result == true) {`, а если не true, тогда из функции вернется undefined

Comment: логика была в том чо когда пользователь введет буквы функция повториться а если нет то вернет то что он вписал

Comment: все с true или false нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в том, что в части где

```
 if (result == true) {
    return content;
} else {
    getNum();
}
```

в блоке else ничего не возвращается. Попробуйте вместо простого вызова сделать

`return getNum()`

Comment: Большое спасибо)